# My function does not return anything; terminal enters some purgatory?

Tags: c, return

So, I'm writing a very simple function to approximate the value of pi using reimann's sum on a fourth of a unit circle. This is my code:

```
double pi_approx(unsigned int n) 
{
    double width = 1 / n;
    double sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0 ; i <= 1 ; i += width)
    {
        sum += width * (1 - i * i);
    }
    return 4 * sum;
}
```

But when I run it on my terminal, it just enters this state where I can kinda just type whatever? What is that state and why am I entering it? How can I avoid that?

Comment: I don't follow. This is the only code in the file you compiled? There's no entry point? Post a [mcve].

Comment: `i+=width` will always result in just `i` because it is integer arithmetic.

Comment: The only entry (which is in another file) is this: 

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    pi_approx(25);
}

as a test

Comment: @kaylum ah thank you! But I'm still having the same issue?

Comment: Still having the same issue after doing what?

Comment: @kaylum after changing i to double

Comment: `width = 1 / n;` -> `width = 1.0 / n;`. Please use a debugger or use basic debug print statements. You can easily find the problem or at least narrow down the problem with some basic debugging.

Comment: Even with `double i`, given slight rounding errors in repeatedly `i += width` and causing `i <= 1` to end too soon, code is likely better off with `for (unsigned i=0; i<= n; i++) { double d = width*i; sum += width * (1 - d * d); }`

Comment: this line: `double width = 1 / n;` will always result n `width` = 0.0 because it will use integer division

Answer (score 4):

Two problems, both a result of integer arithmetic.

1. As **kaylum** pointed out in the comments. `i+=width` doesn't modify `i` when `i` is an integer and `width < 1`.
2. `1 / n` is zero, so `width` is zero and your loop variable never updates.

So, with these issues in mind:

```
double pi_approx(unsigned int n) 
{
    double width = 1.0 / n; // One double operand, so n is promoted.
    double sum = 0;
    for(double i = 0 ; i <= 1 ; i += width)
    {
        sum += width * (1 - i * i);
    }
    return 4 * sum;
}
```

Comment: all those literals should also be `double` rather than `int`.  I.E: `double sum = 0.0;`  and `for( double i=0.0; i<=1.0; i+= width)` and `sum += width* (1.0 =i*1);`  and finally `return 4.0 * sum;`  Depending on implicit conversion is a excellent way to get some nasty surprises